# on hover overflow div

Tags: html, css

I have one project and want to do dynamic effect on div when user hover the div.
I am trying to this effect using css3 but i have overflow color problem with the div on hover.

Please help me to solve the problem.
My code is here

```css
.product-box a:hover .prodiv2:before
{
 content:""; 
 background:rgba(247,146,45,0.6); 
 display:block; 
 width:100%; 
 height:100%; z-index:1; 
 position:absolute; 
 left:0; 
 top:0;
 margin-right:100px !important;
 margin:0 auto !important;
}
.prodiv2 img
{
 width:100% !important;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE Html>
<html>
  <head>
     <title></title> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 rowm">
           <div class="product-box">
               <a href="continuous_parison.php">
            <div class="prodiv2">
       <img src="http://aew.worldwebinfotech.in/images/card1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">         
       <div class="prodiv3">
          <h2>Continuous<br>Parison Series</h2>
          <p>Ranging from : 200 ML -5000ML</p>
          <button class="link-icon">View</button>
                      </div>
      </div>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 rowm">
   <div class="product-box">
    <a href="deflashing_machine.php">
     <div class="prodiv2">
      <img src="http://aew.worldwebinfotech.in/images/card1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="prodiv3">
       <h2>Auto Deflashing<br>Series</h2>
       <p>Ranging from : 200ML- 5LTR</p>
       <button class="link-icon">View</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want to on hover only for image?

Comment: no i want to on hover for all but i want to remove extra color from left side & right side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in your css

```
.product-box{
   position:relative;
   float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thank for your support